# Game of life - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, html5, game-of-life, canvas

I would like to kindly ask others to review my code. I'd like suggestions, criticisms, and discussions on what is good and what could be done better.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.gameOfLife');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create an array
const canvasWidth = 100;
const canvasHeight = 100;
canvas.width = 3 * canvasWidth;
canvas.height = 3 * canvasHeight;
let gameBoard = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
let gameBoard2 = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
let gameBoard3 = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

function createBoard(width, height) {
  let board = new Array(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    board [i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++){
      board[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  return board;
}

function randomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function randomPos() {
  const x = randomNumber(canvasWidth);
  const y = randomNumber(canvasHeight);
  return [x, y];
}

function randomBoard(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 0.2 * canvasHeight * canvasWidth; i++) {
    const [x, y] = randomPos();
    arr[x][y] = 1;
  }
}

function drawBoard(arr) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j++){
      if (arr[i][j] === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#012345";
        ctx.fillRect(i*3, j*3, 3, 3);
      }
    }
  }
}

// calculate new cycle

function checkSurrounding(x, y) {
  let sum = 0;

  startX = x-1 < 0 ? x : x-1;
  stopX = x+1 >= canvasWidth ? x : x+1;
  startY = y-1 < 0 ? y : y-1;
  stopY = y+1 >= canvasHeight ? y : y+1;

  for (let i = startX ; i <= stopX; i++) {
    for (let j = startY ; j <= stopY; j++) {
      if (i !== x || j !== y) {
        sum += gameBoard[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

function deadOrAlive(x, y) {
  const surround = checkSurrounding(x, y);

  if (gameBoard[x][y] === 1 && (surround === 2 || surround === 3)) return 1;
  else if (gameBoard[x][y] === 0 && surround === 3) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

function nextGene() {
  let newBoard = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j++) {
      newBoard[i][j] = deadOrAlive(i, j);
    }
  }

  gameBoard = newBoard;
  drawBoard(newBoard);

}


randomBoard(gameBoard);
drawBoard(gameBoard);

setInterval(nextGene, 150);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Game of Life - Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas class="gameOfLife" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

<style>
  body {
    background-color: #ffc600;
  }
  .gameOfLife{
    margin: 15px auto;
    background-color: #ff6c00;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Any time I see someone writing a Game Of Life program I always suggest: implement Gosper's Algorithm. You will learn a *lot* about the power of purely functional data structures and memoization. Once you can compute trillions of generations a second on a board with trillions of cells, naive implementations seem trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gone over the code briefly and looked at a couple optimizations, but haven't come up with any drastic changes. I will try to go over it again when I find time.

## What is good

I like how the various functions are generally short. And the CSS/HTML is very simple too! It is a nice use of the canvas.

## Suggestions

### Iterations

Anytime you iterate over an array using a `for` loop, consider using a functional approach like [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). That way, you won't have to handle the bookkeeping of iterating the variable (e.g. `var i`) and indexing into the array. For more information, I recommend going through [these exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/). Though be aware that functional approaches are not always optimal/faster.

#### Creating board:

Inspired by the comment from Longfei Wu on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript), the function to create the board could take on a functional approach using [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function createBoard(width, height) {
  return Array(width).fill(0).map(function() {
    return Array(height).fill(0);
  });
}
```

And if you are open to using ES-6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), that can be even shorter:

```
function createBoard(width, height) {
  let board = Array(width).fill(0).map(() => Array(height).fill(0));
  return board;
}
```

See comparison in [this jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/create-board/1). When I ran it in Chrome the array fill-map approach was faster, though the opposite was true in Firefox, Mobile Safari and *emphasized text*Edge.

#### Drawboard:

[.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be used here instead of the `for` statements:

```
function drawBoard(arr) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  arr.forEach(function(innerArray, i) {//  for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i++) {
    innerArray.forEach(function(cell, j) {//for (let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j++){
      if (cell === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#012345";
        ctx.fillRect(i*3, j*3, 3, 3);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And the same is true for `nextGene()`.

#### deadOrAlive()

Because `checkSurrounding()` checks 3-9 spaces around the given cell, I see cases where it returns values greater than 3. Should `deadOrAlive()` have logic in those cases? It appears that it only has logic for return values of 2 and 3.

*Updated snippet:*

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.gameOfLife');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create an array
const canvasWidth = 100;
const canvasHeight = 100;
canvas.width = 3 * canvasWidth;
canvas.height = 3 * canvasHeight;
let gameBoard = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
let gameBoard2 = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
let gameBoard3 = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

function createBoard(width, height) {
  return Array(width).fill(0).map(function() {
    return Array(height).fill(0);
  });
}

function randomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function randomPos() {
  const x = randomNumber(canvasWidth);
  const y = randomNumber(canvasHeight);
  return [x, y];
}

function randomBoard(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 0.2 * canvasHeight * canvasWidth; i++) {
    const [x, y] = randomPos();
    arr[x][y] = 1;
  }
}

function drawBoard(arr) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  arr.forEach(function(innerArray, i) {//  for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i++) {
    innerArray.forEach(function(cell, j) {//for (let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j++){
      if (cell === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#012345";
        ctx.fillRect(i*3, j*3, 3, 3);
      }
    });
  });
}

// calculate new cycle

function checkSurrounding(x, y) {
  let sum = 0;

  startX = x-1 < 0 ? x : x-1;
  stopX = x+1 >= canvasWidth ? x : x+1;
  startY = y-1 < 0 ? y : y-1;
  stopY = y+1 >= canvasHeight ? y : y+1;

  for (let i = startX ; i <= stopX; i++) {
    for (let j = startY ; j <= stopY; j++) {
      if (i !== x || j !== y) {
        sum += gameBoard[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

function deadOrAlive(x, y) {
  const surround = checkSurrounding(x, y);

  if (gameBoard[x][y] === 1 && (surround === 2 || surround === 3)) return 1;
  else if (gameBoard[x][y] === 0 && surround === 3) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

function nextGene() {
  let newBoard = createBoard(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  newBoard.forEach(function(innerArray, i) {//  for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i++) {
    innerArray.forEach(function(cell, j) {//for (let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j++){
      newBoard[i][j] = deadOrAlive(i, j);
    });
  });

  gameBoard = newBoard;
  drawBoard(newBoard);

}


randomBoard(gameBoard);
drawBoard(gameBoard);

setInterval(nextGene, 150);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Game of Life - Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas class="gameOfLife" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

<style>
  body {
    background-color: #ffc600;
  }
  .gameOfLife{
    margin: 15px auto;
    background-color: #ff6c00;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: I like the way you create the board and interate thru. I will use this in my future projects.
At the begining the x in arrow function was unclear for me:
`let board = Array(width).fill(0).map(x => Array(height).fill(0));`
you can remove x from arrow function and use just `() => Ar...`

Comment: cool -yeah empty parentheses is the simplest form, since there are no parameters. I have updated my answer for that section.

Comment: I'm a bit critical of switching `for` loops to `forEach()`, since this is tagged [tag:performance]. While it is a more idiomatic approach, it is definitely less performant.

Comment: Patrick- that is what I was implying by the last sentence of the paragraph under *Iterations*. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of small points.

First, why is it an array of ints?  Cells are dead or alive, so why not bools?  You spend a lot of keystrokes turning integers into bools, and then turning those bools right back into integers. Just keep them bools!

Second, supposing that you do go with bools: this code can be made much simpler:

```
function deadOrAlive(x, y) {
  const surround = checkSurrounding(x, y);
  if (gameBoard[x][y] === 1 && (surround === 2 || surround === 3)) return 1;
  else if (gameBoard[x][y] === 0 && surround === 3) return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

Could instead be

```
function deadOrAlive(x, y) {
  const surround = checkSurrounding(x, y);
  return surround === 3 || surround === 2 && gameBoard[x][y];
}
```

or, if you stick with ints, then

```
function deadOrAlive(x, y) {
  const surround = checkSurrounding(x, y);
  return surround === 3 || surround === 2 && gameBoard[x][y] === 1;
}
```

Note that in this code we now *check the cheapest thing first*, always.  If surround is 3, then we're done without doing any more work. If surround is not 3 and not 2, then again, we're done without doing any more work.  Only if surround is 2 do we do a double-array access.

Third: this inner-loop code spends a lot of code on the page, and a lot of execution time, figuring out how to loop:

```
function checkSurrounding(x, y) {
  let sum = 0;
  startX = x-1 < 0 ? x : x-1;
  stopX = x+1 >= canvasWidth ? x : x+1;
  startY = y-1 < 0 ? y : y-1;
  stopY = y+1 >= canvasHeight ? y : y+1;
  for (let i = startX ; i <= stopX; i++) {
    for (let j = startY ; j <= stopY; j++) {
      if (i !== x || j !== y) {
        sum += gameBoard[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Another possible technique is to surround your board by a one-cell zone of death; these cells start dead and never become alive.  If you simply change your loop to:

```
for (let i = 1; i < canvasWidth - 1; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < canvasHeight - 1; j++) {
    newBoard[i][j] = deadOrAlive(i, j);
  }
}
```

then you can change your inner loop to... well, not a loop!

```
function checkSurrounding(x, y) {
  return 
    (gameBoard[x-1][y-1] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x-1][y] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x-1][y+1] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x][y-1] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x][y+1] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x+1][y-1] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x+1][y] ? 1 : 0) + 
    (gameBoard[x+1][y+1] ? 1 : 0);
}
```

(Again, assuming that it is bools, not ints. If you keep it ints, then you just get to do the sum.)

Also, it should be `countSurrounding`, since that's what it does.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Using bools is good idea. I will consider that for version 2.
I have a question about `function checkSurrounding(x, y) `. 
What do you think about reducing the array instead of this long sum?

Comment: @Kamil: I think that if the task of the code is "add eight things together" then a sum with eight things in it is *very appropriate*.